# Combining a list and multiple dictionaries to nested dictionary - python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a nested dictionary out of a list that should be the keys and dictionaries that are the values of that nested dict.

Input:

```
l = [key1, key2, key3]

d1 = {string11:value11, string12:value12, string13:value13}
d2 = {string21:value21, string22:value22, string23:value23}
d3 = {string31:value31, string32:value32, string33:value33}
```

Output:

```
{key1 : {string11:value11, string12:value12, string13:value13}, key2 : {string21:value21, string22:value22, string23:value23}, key3 : {string31:value31, string32:value32, string33:value33}}
```

So far, I tried to zip the list and a dict but this creates another dict, not a nested dict.

`ld = dict(zip(l,d))`

Do I need to create a list of d1,d2,d3 first? How can I combine `l` and the list of dicts then?

Comment: `ld = dict(zip(l,[d1, d2, d3]))`

Comment: Why do you have so many variables with the same dict structure in the first place? Why not just create them as a nested dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you'll need to create the list of d first

```
dict(zip(l, [d1, d2, d3]))
```

When you pass a dictionary in as an iterator, its values will be iterated over (The keys won't be included). Hence why `dict(zip(l, d1))` will produce a single dictionary rather than a nested one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. You could for example use dict comprehension:

```
ld = {k: d for k, d in zip(l, [d1, d2, d3])}
```